# SYSDATE with TimeStamp Format need to include in Jenkins Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Anyone know how to get SYSDATE while running Jenkins build, it should be in this format: 24Aug20221005 (sysdatewithtimestamp)

please let me know.

Thanks,
Harish.

Comment: What kind of format is that? Why not 202208241005, which makes sense?

Comment: Thanks Lan W for the reply, As per Team Requirement, They asked me in this format: 24Aug20221005. Can you plz let me know Which Plugin you have used to get this format 202208241005.

Comment: That's a stupid requirement.and should be challenged. [`date  [+FORMAT]`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)

Comment: [Plugins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search?query=build%20time%20stamp) options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `date +%d%b%Y%H%M` to get a date like `25Aug20221431`

If you want to change the date you can simply look this up yourself with `date --help`.

You can get this in the Jenkinsfile as a environment variable like this:

```
env.MY_DATE = sh(
    script: """
        date +%d%b%Y%H%M
    """, returnStdout: true
)
```

or in a bash script like this:

```
sh '''
    MY_DATE=$(date +%d%b%Y%H%M)
    echo $MY_DATE
'''
```